# Property 'store' does not exist on type { } - MobX & React & TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, mobx

I keep getting error "Property 'store' does not exist on type '{}'." from TypeScript when using Next.js with Mobx. I'm using Next.js v14.1.0 with the app router setting.

How to properly define the type for state store in Next.js?

Additional description of my code, currently my `ObservableClickStore` is inside the same page (`page.tsx`) with `Home` component.

`Home` is a component that will be passed again to `Games`, and `page.tsx` will render `Games` (I'm not sure also with this approach, seems inefficient and redundant.

```
// ./src/app/page.tsx

class ObservableClickStore {
  counter: number = 0;
  openedCards: ICard[] = [];
  clickedCards: ICard[] = [];
  nonShuffledCharacters: ICard[] = [
    { text: "Saya", answer: "I", isRevealed: false },
    // clickCard function logic. Removed to make concise...
  ]

  characters = this.nonShuffledCharacters.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this, {
      counter: observable,
      characters: observable,
      clickCard: action,
      toggleIsRevealed: action,
      clearClickedCards: action,
      reset: action,
    });
    autorun(() => console.log(this.report));
  }

  get report() {
    return this.characters;
  }

  toggleIsRevealed = (card: ICard) => {
    const index = this.characters.indexOf(card)
    this.characters[index].isRevealed = !this.characters[index].isRevealed;
  }

  clearClickedCards = () => {
    this.clickedCards = []
  }

  reset = () => {
    // reset function logic. Removed to make concise...
  }

  clickCard = (card: ICard) => {
    // clickCard function logic. Removed to make concise...
  }
}

const observableClickStore = new ObservableClickStore();

const Home = observer(({ store }) => {

  const backside = "";
  const quizCardList = store.characters.map((character: ICard, i: number) =>
    <div className='m-1' key={i}>
      <div onClick={() => store.clickCard(character)}>
        <QuizCard revealCard={character.isRevealed} backside={backside} frontside={character.text} />
      </div>
    </div >
  )

  return (
    <>
      // render HTML...
    <>
})

const Games = () => {
  return <Home store={observableClickStore} />
}

export default Games;
```

Comment: Are you using the pages or the app router? Is this component a page? Also, can show where the store is defined?

Comment: Hi @YoussoufOumar, thank you very much for your time and interest on my question. I'm using app router in NextJS v14.1.0. This `Home` component should be a page, but i don't understand how to write it to be a page component with store props passed on it (please let me know if you know the best practice). My `ObservableClickStore` is inside the same page (`page.tsx`) with `Home` component . I have updated above code for clearer understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell the `observer` which type of store it's passing to your page like so:

```
const observableClickStore = new ObservableClickStore();

const Home = observer<{ store: ObservableClickStore }>(({ store }) => {
  // ...
  return <></>;
});

const Games = () => {
  return <Home store={observableClickStore} />;
};

export default Games;
```